# Fancybox to the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I show a pop-up with javascript Fancybox on page load. My problem is, that pop-up shows at the **center of the web page** **and not at center of the screen**. So pop-up is actually moved down and user do not see it, until he scroll down. But I also included centerOnScroll, so pop-up goes down, when you scroll down and you can not see it in any way.
Could someone help me to place my pop-up to the center of the screen? Thanks a lot!

Here is my part of code:

```
$("#hidden-link").fancybox({
    centerOnScroll: true,
    overlayColor: "#000",
    overlayOpacity: 0.9,
    modal: true

}).trigger('click');
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically this isn't an answer. My first suggestion would be to upgrade and use the latest version of fancybox instead.

The method "centerOnScroll" is from Fancybox 1 - I would suggest using version 2 instead which fixes is a lot of problems that version 1 had. You might find that simply upgrading to the latest version fixes your problem.

Version 2 is available here and has many new features: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

See how you get on with version 2. If you are still having trouble show us more of your code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I now use version 2 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is add to website css

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

And fancybox will position image at the screen center.